# Работа с чекбоксами и выводом информации

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть js скрипт который с помощью массива выводит рандомные предложения, а так же есть чек боксы, мне нужно сделать кнопку которая будет проверять правильно ли стоит чекбокс и от этого выдавать соответствующий алерт. Для каждого предложения разные чекбоксы являются правильными.

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы вы предоставили ваш код, чтобы люди смогли дать ответ на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

нужно использовать `:checked` в селекторах элементов

если использовать jQuery:

```
    if($('селекторы правильных чекбоксов через запятую и :checked в конце').length && !$('селекторы не правильных чекбоксов через запятую и :checked в конце').length) alert('Ответ правильный');
```

но есть много параметров, по которым нужно проверять, все зависит от той логики, которую вы хотите использовать...

небольшой пример:

присвоим чекбоксам с правильными ответами класс true, а с неправильными класс false, для примера

```
<input type="checkbox" class="true"> правильный ответ<br>
<input type="checkbox"  class="false"> не правильный ответ<br>
<input type="checkbox"  class="false"> не правильный ответ
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
if($('.true:checked').length == $('.true').length && !$('.false:checked').length) alert('Ответ абсолютно правильный!');
else if($('.true:checked').length && $('.false:checked').length) alert('Ответ с ошибками!');
else if(!$('.true:checked').length && $('.false:checked').length) alert('Ответ неправильный!');
});

});
</script>
```